# ¿Es posible realizar un codigo autoincrementable sin que repita en otro formulario al mismo tiempo?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un formulario en la que muestra un código, la idea era que incremente en la BD respecto a los registro, si tengo 10 registros saldría 11, mi error es¿que pasaría si ese formulario la usan varias personas y en algunos por decirlo así sale el mismo código?

Ejemplo : A11

He estado buscando pero no resuelve mi duda,solo una pero era realizar un monton de cosas en la bd,cosa que solo busco algo sencillo, que podría usar para resolver este dilema?
Es posible lo que digo?

Pdta :
No es llave primaria.
Estoy usando que el el código salga como una alerta después de registrar pero quiero saber si es posible lo que dije antes :D 
No random.

Comment: Hola @francovargas , que has intentado hasta ahora?, tienes algún código para mostrarnos y ver cual es el error o para ayudarte, por otra parte, este tipo de pregunta no cumple con los estándares del sitio SOes, te recomiendo que mires [ask]. Saludos.

Comment: dices que no es llave primaria dicho codigo, podrias crear otro cambio de la misma manera autoincrementable.. y la final de grabar los datos hcer una consulta del registro grabado y mostrar el codigo de tu tabla

Comment: Cuando se abra el formulario vas a crear un nuevo registro en blanco que te dará el ID, podrías poner una columna que tenga un estado que te indique que ese Row se esta editando o algo por el estilo, cuando vallas a guardar el formulario, en ves de INSERTAR lo que harás es ACTUALIZAR la tabla utilizando el ID que se te dio previamente, también deberías de cambiar el estado de la columna que te dice el estado del ROW a completado o algo así. Es como que reservas el "ROW" para ese registro que se va a insertar, en caso de que no se complete el registro podrías borrar el ROW o marcarlo como "Inco

Comment: Voy a intentarlo y te digo como va, gracias!